# Nuke Viewer set framerange trouble

Tags: python, api, viewer, nuke

I'm writing a timeline synchronization script in Nuke10. 
I should change global frame settings. Example:

```
nuke.root().knob('first_frame').setValue(1)
nuke.root().knob('last_frame').setValue(100)
```

After that i should change viewer playback range. Example:

```
vv = nuke.activeViewer().node()
vv['frame_range_lock'].setValue(True)
vv['frame_range'].setValue('5-40')
```

Separately it's worked. But together - not. At start i have global frame range 1-10. And when i run all that's lines - frame range set to 1-100 but playback range set to 5-10.

I add command in the middle of the script to check playback range:

```
nuke.root().knob('first_frame').setValue(1)
nuke.root().knob('last_frame').setValue(100)

x = vv.playbackRange()
print(x)

vv['frame_range_lock'].setValue(True)
vv['frame_range'].setValue('5-40')
```

it's print:

```
# Result: 1-10
```

I think the problem is that the data in the viewer is not updated until the script finishes running.

How do I force a nuke to refresh the viewer?

Or there may be a command waiting to complete the update of previous commands?

Or it can be necessary to specify in a viewer a frame range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to say viewer node to redraw then it will update range properly.

Here is a working example

```
vv = nuke.activeViewer().node()
nuke.root().knob('first_frame').setValue(1)
nuke.root().knob('last_frame').setValue(100)

vv.redraw()
vv['frame_range_lock'].setValue(True)
vv['frame_range'].setValue('25-40')
x = vv.playbackRange()
print(x)
```